# Specific Sorting Algorithm in dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort a dictionary in this way:

I have a list of 9 randoms letters : ['A', 'R', 'E', 'T', 'R', 'I', 'E', 'D', 'S']

and a letter can occur multiple times like T, R and E in this example.

I also have a list of French words. It contains 365 000 words so my algorithm has to be powerful and quick.

My goal is to search for the longuest words that I can form with those 9 random letters and then print those words.

I already made some code but I want to optimize it and I have an idea, but I want to make sure its possible to do without using syntax I never used because it's for school and I have to do it in this way.

So my idea: search for the length of the longest word that I can form with those letters. Then concentrate on words of that length and search for those who their letters are in my 9 random letters. Then again take those words and search for those who have same letter occurrence than in my 9 random_letters.

BUT the problem: if I do that, it works but only for certain cases where the length of the longest word is 9, because when the maximum length possible is 8 or less, if my algorithm found a word that use not all of my random_letters but it's length is 9, it will conclude that the maximum length is 9 and search for words who have the same occurrence and it will not find any word.

My temporary solution: search directly the right words by occurrence but it's not optimal, and it will check 365 000 words and I want to avoid useless operations.

My question: is it possible to realise what I want (in my way or another) with basic syntax? Because I've seen some codes but there are complex or use syntax I can't use because not seen in school.

Comment: ??? why -1 on my question ??? If you don't want to help just pass please !

Comment: You probably got a down-vote because you didn't post any code, and because the explanation of your algorithm is a little hard to understand in places. It can be easier to explain an algorithm to other programmers using code, or pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed up this process is to quickly check that the letters of each word in the word list are a subset of the letters in your letter list. This is fast because set operations are fast in Python. If that test passes, you can then use a slower test to make sure that each letter in the word occurs a valid number of times.

The code below uses the `collections` and `itertools` modules. It can be done without those modules, but it's not as neat. :)

As my word list I used the Scrabble OD5.zip list from http://www.3zsoftware.com/fr/wordmagic/listes.php which contains 378975 words (in lower case, with no accents); the uncompressed file size is 4169985 bytes.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

fname = 'french_word_list_OD5.txt'

letters = ['a', 'r', 'e', 't', 'r', 'i', 'e', 'd', 's']
letterset = set(letters)
letter_counts = Counter(letters)

found = []
with open(fname) as f:
    for word in f:
        word = word.strip()
        # Does the word only use letters found in letterset?
        if letterset.issuperset(word):
            # Check that the word doesn't use too many of any letter 
            if all(len(list(g)) <= letter_counts[k] 
                for k, g in groupby(sorted(word))):
                found.append(word)

print(len(found), 'solutions found')

# Sort the words by length
found.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

# Print some of the longest words
for word in found:
    if len(word) < 8:
        break
    print(word, len(word))
```

**output**

```
507 solutions found
deratiser 9
deterrais 9
detireras 9
aretiers 8
asteride 8
dateries 8
deratise 8
desertai 8
desirera 8
destrier 8
deterrai 8
deterras 8
detirera 8
editeras 8
etireras 8
itereras 8
ratieres 8
reeditas 8
reiteras 8
residera 8
resterai 8
retardes 8
retersai 8
retraies 8
siderera 8
stadiere 8
stererai 8
tarieres 8
terserai 8
triedres 8
```

This script took less than 2 seconds on my old 2GHz machine. It will take a little longer on the first run, since the OS will cache the data file.

---

Here's a version that doesn't import any modules.

It tests if a word is valid by iterating over its letters and seeing if each letter is in `temp`, which is a copy of the `letters` list. If a letter is found in `temp` it's removed so that words that have too many of a particular letter will fail the test.

This version only saves the longest words that it finds, but it's easy to modify it so that it saves all of the words that can be made from `letters`.

```
fname = 'french_word_list_OD5.txt'

letters = ['a', 'r', 'e', 't', 'r', 'i', 'e', 'd', 's']
letterset = set(letters)

# A list to store the words that can be built from the permitted letters
found = []
# The length of the current longest word in `found`
hilen = 1

with open(fname) as f:
    for word in f:
        word = word.strip()
        # Does the word only use letters found in letterset?
        if letterset.issuperset(word):
            # Check that the word doesn't use too many of any letter 
            temp = letters[:]
            for c in word:
                if c in temp:
                    temp.remove(c)
                else:
                    break
            else:
                # We only get here if the `break` isn't executed
                # Save word if its length is >= current longest word
                wordlen = len(word)
                if wordlen >= hilen:
                    hilen = wordlen
                    found.append(word)

print(len(found), 'solutions found')

# Sort the words by length
found.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

# Print only the longest words
for word in found:
    if len(word) == hilen:
        print(word)
```

**output**

```
11 solutions found
deratiser
deterrais
detireras
```

---

This is a simplified version of the previous one. It doesn't do the subset test, which makes it nearly twice as slow.

```
fname = 'french_word_list_OD5.txt'

letters = ['a', 'r', 'e', 't', 'r', 'i', 'e', 'd', 's']

# A list to store the words that can be built from the permitted letters
found = []
# The length of the current longest word in `found`
hilen = 1

with open(fname) as f:
    for word in f:
        word = word.strip()
        # Check that each letter in `word` is in `letters`
        temp = letters[:]
        for c in word:
            if c in temp:
                temp.remove(c)
            else:
                break
        else:
            # We only get here if the `break` isn't executed
            # Save word if its length is >= current longest word
            wordlen = len(word)
            if wordlen >= hilen:
                hilen = wordlen
                found.append(word)

print(len(found), 'solutions found')

# Sort the words by length
found.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

# Print only the longest words
for word in found:
    if len(word) == hilen:
        print(word)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but unfortunately I didn't learn anything you wrote because you're using a library. This exercie for my school is doing it in the easiest way possible, without any libraries. I work on that exercice all day, I think I'll talk some schoolmate for trying to figure how I'll do that

Comment: @NikolaMitrovic Both of the libraries that I used are in the standard libraries that always come with Python. As I said, it can be done without those library functions, and I've added two new versions to my answer that don't import anything.